# connect to external mysqli from docker container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, ssh-tunnel

Host: ubuntu 22.04, docker image: php:7.2-fpm (+nginx:alpine), laravel: 5.2.

For some legacy laravel project I need to test some feature that uses sphinx. It's not configured locally so it's easier to connect to server where it's already working. I use docker for my local setup and I want to connect from docker container to sphinx that is on remote server using ssh port forwarding `ssh -f -N <username>@<host> -L <port>:<ip>:<port>`

In my docker-compose.yaml there is extra_hosts setting for accessing local machine from inside of the php container.

```
extra_hosts:
 - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Inside the vendor code it's trying to connect like this:

```
 $conn = mysqli_init();
 ...
 $conn->real_connect($data['host'], null, null, null, (int) $data['port']);
```

host is http://host.docker.internal.

It gives me an error:

> ```
> mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. Without http:// doesn't work as well.
> ```

If I try this directly on my local machine (host: 127.0.0.1) after forwarding port - connection is established, real_connect works just fine.

I feel like there should be a special service ip for my local host (additionally to host.docker.internal) or a way to set it up for that kind of thing.

**UPD**: if I use just host.docker.internal, mysqli gives me "Connection refused" error.

**UPD2**: Tried host gateway ip (172.25.0.1) from docker network inspect. Same "Connection refused".

```
root@e279887dc67b:/var/www# nslookup host.docker.internal
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

** server can't find host.docker.internal: NXDOMAIN

root@e279887dc67b:/var/www# nslookup 172.25.0.1
1.0.25.172.in-addr.arpa name = maksim-linux-laptop.
1.0.25.172.in-addr.arpa name = maksim-linux-laptop.local.
```

Comment: What is `host-gateway`? You shouldn't need any special mapping for `host.docker.internal`, by default it maps to the host IP. You also most definitely do not want to include `http://` in your MySQLi _host_ parameter

Comment: @Phil https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541681/9696145 seems like mapping is needed, no?

Comment: Are you running this on a Linux host?

Comment: @Phil yes, I am

Comment: Right, sorry. Not many questions on here using Linux hosts so I just assume Mac or WIndows. Just to confirm, are you only using the `docker` CLI tools or have you installed Docker Desktop for Linux?

Comment: Only CLI, didn't even know about Docker desktop for linux.

Comment: "Without http:// doesn't work as well" - what do you mean by that? MySQL does not communicate over HTTP

Comment: @NicoHaase Yea my bad, I guess I was just trying anything.

Comment: What details are you using for the ports? What is `$data['port']` and what are you using in your `ssh` command `-L` option

Comment: can you connect to the cli in the image and `ping` the remote host? have you tried with the ip address? or maybe a `nslookup hostname` (the docker container may not have dns resolution set up correctly)

Comment: @Phil Well, I'm not ready to share here my productions creds. $data['port'] = <port> in my ssh forwarding. For -L it's <username>@<host>, the standard way of connecting to ssh. I don't think it's an ssh connection since, as I said, it is working directly from the local machine setup (php, nginx) using the same php version.

Comment: I'm not asking for credentials, just the syntax you're using for `-L`. Is it `-L 3306:localhost:3306`, `-L localhost:3306:localhost:3306`, etc?

Comment: @Phil first one. I guess I'll try second one? But instead of localhost though ip: 
3306:<production-remote-ip>:3306

Comment: I'm not asking you to try anything! Just please clarify what you **are using**. You most definitely do not want the second one which is why I was asking.

Comment: @Phil Ok ok, gotcha :D

Comment: @JoSSte
Updated the question to show output of nslookup. 

I tried host gateway ip as well.
maksim-linux-laptop is my linux machine name.

Comment: Honestly don't think this is too broad (have voted to re-open). Seems straight forward... 1) For some reason, `host.docker.internal` is not resolving in the container. This is probably a simple fix regarding docker network modes or something. 2) The container is not able to connect through the host's SSH tunnel. This is the real question here